# Indefinite article before numbers in context

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Tell me please if I have to use the indefinite article before #*nine* in the following context.

> On the scale of 1 to 10, how strong was the pain of having your tooth drilled. Well it was (**a**) nine.

If I need to use **a** there, could you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the article is optional.

The response is idiomatic both with and without the **a**. The choice might depend on exactly what's in the respondent's mind when s/he answers.

If the respondent imagines choosing a number from the numbers presented, the answer is likely to be **a** nine. Similarly a contestant in a TV quiz might choose **the** (number) nine as the question to answer.

On the other hand, if the respondent simply thinks about the scale of pain, responses such as **I would say nine** and **it was about nine** are likely.

It's similar to asking someone throwing dice what s/he has just thrown. The response could be either **I threw a six** or **I threw six**.

In this context, the latter answer cannot be misinterpreted as six throws rather than the number six. Both responses are perfectly clear and idiomatic.